# ElGamal: Why is reusing the same $k$ not secure?

Tags: elgamal-encryption, nonce, key-reuse

I have a question on the encryption process of ElGamal:
$$  
  Y = g ^ a \bmod p \\
  C = g ^ k \bmod p \quad\text{($k$ is chosen randomly)} \\
  D = m \cdot y ^ k \bmod p \\
  \text{Decryption:}\qquad m = C^{(p-1-a)}\cdot D\bmod p
$$

My professor told us we should know why it's bad to use the same values for the variables $a$ and $k$ more than once, but he didn't say why. I guess that if the same values for $a$ and $k$ are used several times, the attacker could calculate the unknown values if he is able to capture the traffic, but I don't know how.

How could an attacker proceed there?

Comment: Hint: suppose that attacker captured two encrypted values with the same $k$, and he knows the corresponding plaintext to one of them; what can he determine about the plaintext of the other?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't really get the point. In ElGamal the variables (p, g and y) are public and if you send an encrypted message m you also send d and c. So you could calculate the k even if you haven't intercepted a 2nd message (to calc. k you solve g^k = c mod p).
And even when you get a 2nd message encrypted with the same k, the problem you have to solve didn't get easier (it's the same mod p).
The only problem by using the same k more than once is in my opinion that if the attacker had captured more messages and he get the k he could decrypt all other messages.

Comment: "to calc. k you solve g^k = c mod p"; could you give a summary of how you would solve this equation, assuming p was a 2048 bit prime?

Comment: With a 2048 bit prime it's nearly impossible the only possibility I see is by splitting it to the subset (p-1) and using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. But also with this it's nearly impossible.
And there I don't understand the specification of not reusing the same k. Because even if you use the same k the probability of solving k doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, reusing a value $k$ doesn't help the attacker learn $k$; however what if the attacker was interested in learning something other than $k$?  What if he was interested in (say) the plaintext?  (See my hint...)

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you very much. So by using the same k ElGamal is not secure against Know Plaintext Attacks. Because you can solve the Problem $m_{2}=d_{2} * y^{(-k)}\mod p$ by using the $y^{(-k)}$ which you still have ($y^{(-k)} =d_{1}*m_{1}\mod p$)

Answer (score 3):

In ElGamal encryption like you said for **unknown** $m_1$ and **known** $m_2$ we have:

$m_1: C_1=g^k\ mod\ p,\  D_1=m_1.g^{a.k}$

$m_2: C_2=g^k\ mod\ p,\  D_2=m_2.g^{a.k}$

$k$ is the **same** in both encryptions, by dividing $D_1$ and $D_2$ we have:

${D_1\over D_2}={m_1\over m_2} => D_1.m_2 = D_2.m_1$

$m_2$ , $D_1$ and $D_2$ and are known so now we can calculate $m_1$. This is how can attacker proceed and find unknown $m_1$.